# speed up swfobject

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, swfobject

This is my website: [Instant-YouTube](http://instant-youtube.com/)

As you you can see it takes forever to load. In IE8 and below it even sometimes makes the browser crash. I'm not sure what is causing this. It could be the Clicksor ads but I think it's the swfobjects. I already gzipped the index file. What can I do to speed up the swfobject loading time, or speed up anything else in general??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case - there are tools like pagespeed which can give you some ideas on what to optimize:

http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/#url=http_3A_2F_2Finstant-youtube.com_2F&mobile=false

The timeline in firebug displaying all files loaded is also very helpful in identifying performance problems.

That said: swfobjects gets loaded fairly quickly - actually your page (html) loads in about 100-150 ms. But here are a lot (! more than 200) of files loaded from various servers - of course lots of youtube preview images. Having so many youtube players on one page is probably not the best idea if you'd like to have short page loading times. All the request made to youtube to get the most viewed videos by category will also take some time to complete.
Can't say anything about the ads (I'm using an adblocker), but it looks like clicksor ads load google analytics scripts in turn - and you have so many of them... so many requests. And then there are other ads (chitika?).

So what can you do?

- less flash players
- less ads
- less external resources
- minify and combine your javascript and css files
- Set far future expiry date or max-age for static resources
- ... check out pagespeed recommendations

Comment: Thank's for your time. I'm going to change my website according to your list of suggestions. I now for sure that will work.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox you can use Firebug to measure the time that the individual items need to be loaded. Then you can think of loading them in parallel.

Comment: Thank's. Loading in parallel is a new subject for me. Thank's for mentioning, I don't think I'm going to do that but it's good knowledge for future projects.